# Error: Failed to parse /get_branches.py with script plugin: Inventory script (/get_branches.py) had an execution error:

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

Developed a script to pull hosts from ldap ad, however, getting the above error, things I made sure,
1.) script has executable permissions
2.) script path has been configured in ansible.cfg as below
3.) script starts with a shebang #!/usr/bin/python3

```
inventory = /path/to/script/get_branches.py
```

```
ansible 2.9.6
  config file = /Users/smohamme/ansible_liquibase/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/Users/smohamme/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.7.7 (default, Mar 10 2020, 15:43:03) [Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)]
```

ansible-config dump --only-changed

```
DEFAULT_HOST_LIST(/ansible_liquibase/ansible.cfg) = ['ansible_liquibase/get_branches.py']
DEFAULT_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE(/ansible_liquibase/ansible.cfg) = /.vault_pass
```

the exception it is referring to here is this line in script.py

```
raise AnsibleError("Inventory script (%s) had an execution error: %s " % (path, err))
```

here is the link to the script.py

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/inventory/script.py#L122

can somebody tell me where I am doing wrong,

Further, my script when I run it with python3 it return a perfect json structure format inventory from the ldap.

Adding as per the comment from ran
ansible-inventory -vvvv -i ./get_branches.py --list

output

```
ansible-inventory 2.9.6
  config file = /Users/smohamme/ansible_liquibase/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/Users/smohamme/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible-inventory
  python version = 3.7.7 (default, Mar 10 2020, 15:43:03) [Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)]
Using /Users/smohamme/ansible_liquibase/ansible.cfg as config file
setting up inventory plugins
host_list declined parsing /Users/smohamme/ansible_liquibase/get_branches.py as it did not pass its verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /Users/smohamme/ansible_liquibase/get_branches.py as it did not pass its verify_file() method
yaml declined parsing /Users/smohamme/ansible_liquibase/get_branches.py as it did not pass its verify_file() method
toml declined parsing /Users/smohamme/ansible_liquibase/get_branches.py as it did not pass its verify_file() method
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /Users/smohamme/ansible_liquibase/get_branches.py with script plugin: failed to parse executable inventory script results from
/Users/smohamme/ansible_liquibase/get_branches.py: Syntax Error while loading YAML.   mapping values are not allowed here  The error appears to be in
'<string>': line 3, column 12, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible/inventory/manager.py", line 280, in parse_source
    plugin.parse(self._inventory, self._loader, source, cache=cache)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/inventory/script.py", line 161, in parse
    raise AnsibleParserError(to_native(e))
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /Users/smohamme/ansible_liquibase/get_branches.py with ini plugin: /Users/smohamme/ansible_liquibase/get_branches.py:3:
Expected key=value host variable assignment, got: os
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible/inventory/manager.py", line 280, in parse_source
    plugin.parse(self._inventory, self._loader, source, cache=cache)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/inventory/ini.py", line 138, in parse
    raise AnsibleParserError(e)
[WARNING]: Unable to parse /Users/smohamme/ansible_liquibase/get_branches.py as an inventory source
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
{
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {}
    },
    "all": {
        "children": [
            "ungrouped"
        ]
    }
}
```

after running ./get_branches.py --list I get the output as expected.

```
{
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {
            "abc.example.com": {
                "name": "abc.example.com",
                "cn": "abc",
                "osname": "Windows Server 2016 Standard"
            },
            "abc.example.com": {
                "name": "abc.example.com",
                "cn": "abc",
                "osname": "Windows Server 2016 Standard"
            }
        }
    },
    "non-production": {
        "hosts": [
            "abc.example.com",
            "xyz.example.com"
        ],
        "vars": {},
        "children": []
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64420400/edit) and include the output of `ansible-inventory -vvvv -i /get_branches.py --list` to see what ansible-inventory thinks about things; that is, of course, assuming you have already just run `/get_branches.py --list` by yourself and it reports a-ok (I don't mean `python3 /get_branches.py`: I mean executing the script)

Comment: Your script exit code in not 0: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/inventory/script.py#L121 Debug your script.

Comment: any suggestions daniel ?

Comment: I suggest that you don't call me daniel, and compose an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) _(or post your inventory script, maybe we can spot the error)_ because without the ability to reproduce your failure, no one can explain what is going on